# Replace all numbers following a specific string with another number using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, awk

I have tried several things but got no luck. I have an input file that has a lot of fields like this one

`weight=0.123456`

mixed with other fields. I want to multiply all such weights by a factor, say 100, so I want to see

`weight=12.3456`

in the output file. What's a good way to do that using sed or awk?

Comment: "mixed with other fields" is too vague to be able to script something useful in awk (precisely!). Anyway, the general approach is: a) split the input in fields, trim the 'weight=' part; b) feed bc with that; c) printf what you need

Comment: not even bc, GNU awk supports arithmetic operations

Answer (score 1):

For a simple file containing

```
$ cat input
weight=0.0012
weight=0.0345
```

`$ awk '/weight/{gsub(/weight=/, "")};{ value=$0*100; printf "weight=%s\n", value}' input`

does the trick. More complicated input files need more complicated rules (possibly).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ /weight/{print "weight="$2*100}' file
```